# React Hooks: updating multiple hook states atomically

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is it possible to update multiple hook-defined states atomically? Right now I get a rerender for every setState I call. When using class `setState` it was possible to update multiple state parameter at once.

Example with class style state component:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jj3r9wlzmv

Example with hook state component:
https://codesandbox.io/s/o9w2oo59yq

The hook state example renders twice, where the class style example only renders one additional time.